# How to run forEach with group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I am investigating why I am not able to use `forEach` here:

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="map"]');
checks.forEach(function(index) {
  var value = this.value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="map" value="1"> Asia <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="map" value="2"> Africa <br />
```

Comment: `this` refers to `window` in your code. (also, you only have one name of `map`, the other's name is `mao`)

Comment: Thanks for comment, so how can I get each of check box values here

Comment: Use `index.value`?

Comment: Just change `index` to `check` and then `this.value` to `check.value`.

Comment: ...continuing @CertainPerformance's answer, you need `target.value` instead of `this.value`. as mentioned above `this` refers to global window object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument of the function you gives to `forEach` is not the index, but the element itself, like :

```js
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="map"]');

checks.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="map" value="1"> Asia <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="map" value="2"> Africa <br />
```